# Linux made images are not readable on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, linux, images

I made screenshots on several distros I tried out, copied them to an NTFS drive (under Linux) and I cannot open some of them under Windows (tried photoshop and mspaint). I first thought the files are corrupted, but I can open them under Linux. Any idea about what causing this?

```
mint 17.2 (2015.08.27-31)
    mate x
    cinnamon 0
    xfce x
    kde x
ubuntu  (2015.09.03-05)
    unity 14 x
    unity 15 0/x
    kubuntu 14 x
    xubuntu 15 x
    uumate x
mint 17.2 (2015.09.05)
    cinnamon x
    mate x
    xfce x
    kde x
```

The x means the files are okay, 0/x means that some of them are okay, some of them not, 0 means that I cannot open any file from that batch. As you can see the behavior is not distro dependent.

I have the following error message when I try to upload the file using firefox in windows 7:

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem, the file names contain ":"

```
Screenshot from 2015-09-03 22:35:46.png
Screenshot from 2015-09-05 13_19_57.png
```

I'll write a bash script to rename them. I assume this was fixed between the mentioned dates, that's why it does not show up by a newly installed Mint+Cinnamon. It is strange that by ubuntu 15 images before 2015-09-03 22:51:09 are bad, and images after that time are good on the same system. I don't think I started auto update or something like that, because these are installer screenshots.